# Constructor undefined error and generic class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, generics

I'm trying to develop a generic class and a generic method that allow me to see if an element is inside an array. This is my generic class code :

```
public class RicercaGenerica <T> {
public RicercaGenerica (T[] primoElemento, T secondoElemento)
{
    primo = primoElemento;
    secondo = secondoElemento;
}

public boolean ricerca (T[] primoElemento, T secondoElemento)
{
    for(T e : primoElemento)
    {
        if(e == secondoElemento)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private T[] primo;
private T secondo;
}
```

And this is my tester class :

```
public class TestGenerico {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double toFind = 15.2;
        double[] array1 = {5.1,6.2,3.4,18.9,15.2,16.0};
        RicercaGenerica <Double[], Double> test = new RicercaGenerica<Double[], Double>(array1, toFind);
    }
}
```

I can't compile the code because Eclipse give me this message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Incorrect number of arguments for type RicercaGenerica<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Double[], Double>
    Incorrect number of arguments for type RicercaGenerica<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Double[], Double>

    at testGenerico.TestGenerico.main(TestGenerico.java:10)
```

How can I fix this? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RicercaGenerica` class has only one generic type parameter:

```
RicercaGenerica<Double> test = new RicercaGenerica<>(array1, toFind);
```

You'll also have to change

```
double[] array1
```

to

```
Double[] array1
```